# Convert string to array of objects React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

i have a problem how to convert String to array of objects.

First things first:

I am using Ace editor to capture code String that i want to pass to my axios call.

when I am importing my data from local file

```
let data = [
    { data: `some XML`},
    { data: `some XML`},
  ];

export default data;
```

I iterate this array and send async each item. which is ok.

but I do not want to use the file I want to be able to somehow paste this into Ace editor and then pass it to my call.

BUT Ace editor is capturing this as a String

so it is not valid Array and it has no objects init to iterate. it is just a string. Even if i place it in array state it looks like this array has only one big string in it.... not separated objects.

```
["[
    {data: `some XML`},
    {data: `some XML`},
  ];"]
 "[
    {data: `some XML`},
    {data: `some XML`},
  ];"
```

is there any way to have array of object again?

Comment: you can try eval

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
let array = [
    { data: `some XML`},
    { data: `some XML`},
  ];
  array.forEach(function(record,index) {
      console.log(record.data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.parse()`. However, your keys must be enclosed in quotation marks for it to be valid JSON.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 25

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp). ? It should convert the string into json format. But the string need to be valid to be able to convert to object.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 25